# R how to create a large matrix by combining small blocks of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working on a constrained optimization problem using Lagrange Multiplier method. And I'm trying to build this huge sparse matrix in R in order to calculate the values.

Here's how the matrices would look like. And the link below for the details of the problem if needed.

[image]
[Implementation of Lagrange Multiplier to solve constrained optimization problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246977/implementation-of-lagrange-multiplier-to-solve-constrained-optimization-problem)

Here's the code I've come up with, sorry if my approach seems clumsy to you, since I'm new to matrix manipulation and programming.

First, I imported the 3154 by 30 matrices from a csv file, and then combined all columns into one. Then I created a diagonal matrices to imitate the upper left corner of the matrices.

Then, to imitate the lower left corner of the matrices. I created a 3154x3154 identity matrices and tried to replicate it 30 times.

I have two questions here

1. When I tried to cbind the diagonal sparse matrix, it returned a combination of two lists instead of a matrix. So I had to convert it to matrix, but this is taking too much of my memory. I'd like to know if there's a better way to accomplish this.
2. I want to know if there's a formula for cbind a matrix multiple times. Since I need to replicate the matrix 30 times. I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to get around all the typings. (This was solved thanks to @Jthorpe)

I was gonna do the same thing for the rest of the matrices. I know this is not the best approach to tackle this problem. Please feel free to to suggest any smarter way of doing this. Thanks!

```
library(Matrix)
dist_data=read.csv("/Users/xxxxx/dist_mat.csv", header=T)
c=ncol(dist_data) #number of cluster - 30
n=nrow(dist_data) #number of observations - 3153

#Create a c*n+c+n = 3153*30+3153+3 = 97,773 coefficient matrix
dist_list=cbind(unlist(dist_data))
Coeff_mat=2*.sparseDiagonal(c*n,x = c(dist_list))

diag=.sparseDiagonal(n)
Uin <- do.call(cbind,rep(list(as.matrix(diag)),30))
```

Comment: the only thing that stands out as awkward is that you don's use `dist_list=cbind(unlist(dist_data))` or ``dist_list=cbind(do.call(`c`,dist_data))`` instead all that typing.    Also, the use of magic numbers (94590, and 3153) is not ideal, from a coding style perspective...

Comment: Regarding the second point try this: `Uin <- do.call(cbind,rep(list(as.matrix(diag)),30))`